# Private Gitlab composer repository access

Tags: php, composer-php, gitlab

I am trying to get my composer file to pull a repository from Gitlab but so far it is still asking for my username & password.

```
{
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "composer-pkg-name",
            "version": "0.1.0",
            "type": "package",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://blah@gitlab.com/repo-url,
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": [""]
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "blah/composer-pkg-name": "0.1.0"
},
"config": {
    "gitlab.com": "secret-account-access-token"
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `auth.json` file in your composer home. Eg. /home/username/.config/composer if you use ubuntu

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "gitlab.com": {
            "username": "login",
            "password": "password"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between using gitlab token and username/password?